# How to move picturebox with arrow keys with listbox?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, multithreading

Every things is ok form1+picturebox1 i can use good below codes:

```
   public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(Form1_KeyDown);
        }

        private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            int x = pictureBox1.Location.X;
            int y = pictureBox1.Location.Y;

            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right) x += 5;
            else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left) x -= 5;
            else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up) y -= 5;
            else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Down) y += 5;

            pictureBox1.Location = new Point(x, y);

        }
```

BUT;
if i add listbox to write position picturebox, i can not move picturebox with arrow keys how can i do that?

Comment: Just curious, why did you tag this multithreading?

Comment: Could you explain the part about the listbox? that is not quite clear.

Answer (score 1):

Probalby your listbox gets the focus an not the form, you probably have to listen the listboxs keydown-event.

**EDIT:**

Use this focusable PictureBoxEx and listen to its previewkeydown-event :

```
public class PictureBoxEx : PictureBox
{
    public PictureBoxEx()
    {
        this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.Selectable, true);
    }

    protected override void OnClick(EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Focus();
        base.OnClick(e);
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

Or use the following. with this you don't have to move a control in the form, but just move the image within the control.

```
public class PictureBoxEx : Control
    {
        public PictureBoxEx()
        {
            this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.Selectable | ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint | ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw | ControlStyles.UserPaint | ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);


        }


        protected override void OnClick(EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Select();
            base.OnClick(e);
        }

        private Image _Image;
        public Image Image
        {
            get
            {
                return _Image;
            }
            set
            {
                _Image = value;
                this.Invalidate();
            }
        }

        private Point _ImageLocation = new Point(0,0);
        public Point ImageLocation
        {
            get
            {
                return _ImageLocation;
            }
            set
            {
                _ImageLocation = value;
                this.Invalidate();
            }
        }

        private int _ImageLocationLeft = 0;
        public int ImageLocationLeft
        {
            get
            {
                return _ImageLocationLeft;
            }
            set
            {
                _ImageLocationLeft = value;
                ImageLocation = new Point(value, ImageLocationTop);
            }
        }

        private int _ImageLocationTop = 0;
        public int ImageLocationTop
        {
            get
            {
                return _ImageLocationTop;
            }
            set
            {
                _ImageLocationTop = value;
                ImageLocation = new Point(ImageLocationLeft, value);
            }
        }

        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe)
        {
            if (Image != null)
            {
                pe.Graphics.DrawImage(Image, ImageLocation);
            }
            base.OnPaint(pe);
        }

        protected override void OnPreviewKeyDown(PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyData == Keys.Up || e.KeyData == Keys.Down || e.KeyData == Keys.Left || e.KeyData == Keys.Right)
            e.IsInputKey = true;
            base.OnPreviewKeyDown(e);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to [Invalidate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invalidate%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)  which will redraw your UI; In order to see those changes that you made.

You can choose to redraw certain regions with the overload `Invalidate(Region region)` or you can invalidate the whole control by doing `Control.Invalidate()`.

Try addign: `this.Invalidate();` after you've created the new `Point`.

You can also use [`Refresh()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.refresh.aspx) which will invalidate and force the control to redraw.

Here is an MSDN Article about ["How to: Handle Keyboard input at Form Level"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171538.aspx) you might want to read that and compare it to your current code. You might want to change KeyDown to KeyPress instead. And also as I said in my comment, it really should work without forcing the form to redraw using `Invalidate()` or `Refresh()`.

Comment: Thanks but not work:   pictureBox1.Location = new Point(x, y);
            this.Invalidate();
            this.Refresh();

Comment: @Phsika, nothing happens? Are you sure that the event is even fired? It should work even without Invalidate/Refresh, but to be sure, leave them there for now. Put a breakpoint in that event and see if it triggers.

Comment: @Phsika, What part do you not understand? I will try to clearify it.

Comment: i think that; it is related to threading because they are loading in form load but if i click arrow keys to move my box everything is locked

Comment: @Phsika, Can you put a `MessageBox.Show(@"Keyboard pressed!");` in your `Form1_KeyDown` to see that it is actually called? Otherwise it might bee as @Wowa said, your `ListBox` takes the focus from the form, hence, your  keystrokes wont be caught.