# How do I make my picture box move using the arrow keys?

Tags: c#, animation, picturebox, keydown

I have created an animation using C# in Visual Studio, within a pictureBox using multiple images of pacman. I am now attempting to get the pictureBox to move around the form (up, down, right and left) by using the arrow keys but I cannot seem to get it working. Can anyone help me figure out why the pictureBox won't move?
Thanks
Here is my code so far:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Common;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Week9
{
public partial class Pacman : Form
{
    private Image[] pacmanImage = new Image[4];
    private int currentMouthPosition = 0;
    private int xPosition = 0;
    private int yPosition = 0;

    // The index of the current frame.
    private int FrameNum = 0;

    public Pacman()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.KeyDown +=newSystem.Windows.Forms.KeyEventHandler(this.Pacman_KeyDown);
    }


    private void picFrame_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics g = e.Graphics;
        g.DrawImage(pacmanImage[currentMouthPosition], xPosition, yPosition, 32, 32);

    }

    // Load the images.
    private void Pacman_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pacmanImage[0] = Image.FromFile("..\\..\\pac32_left_close.png");
        pacmanImage[1] = Image.FromFile("..\\..\\pac32_left_open.png");
        pacmanImage[2] = Image.FromFile("..\\..\\pac32_left_wide.png");
        pacmanImage[3] = Image.FromFile("..\\..\\pac32_left_widest.png");
        // Display the first frame.
        picFrame.Image = pacmanImage[FrameNum];
    }

    // This is where I have tried to get the pictureBox to move
    private void Pacman_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.KeyCode)
        {
            case Keys.Left:
                picFrame.Left -= 5;
                break;
            case Keys.Right:
                picFrame.Left += 5;
                break;
            case Keys.Up:
                picFrame.Top -= 5;
                break;
            case Keys.Down:
                picFrame.Top += 5;
                break;
        }
    }


    // Display the next image.
    private void tmrNextFrame_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FrameNum = ++FrameNum % pacmanImage.Length;
        picFrame.Image = pacmanImage[FrameNum];
    }

    private void btnStartStop_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tmrNextFrame.Enabled = !tmrNextFrame.Enabled;
        if (tmrNextFrame.Enabled) btnStartStop.Text = "Stop";
        else btnStartStop.Text = "Start";
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: there are plenty of working examples on the internet.. have you tried a `Google Search` on the following `C# moving PictureBox` ?
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/492ecda3-39ff-4fd8-901e-6d1302fab6c7/how-to-let-a-picturebox-move-around-with-the-arrow-keys-in-c?forum=winforms

Comment: Yes I have looked at that example and many others and still can't seem to get it working

Comment: check this link out to..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779515/how-to-move-picturebox-with-arrow-keys-with-listbox

Answer (score 1):

```
private void Pacman_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.KeyCode)
    {
        case Keys.Left:
            mouthcurrentposition = 0;
            picFrame.yPosition -= 10;
            picFrame.Left(); //This should be a method that will draw your pacman
            break;
        case Keys.Right:
            mouthcurrentposition = 1;
            picFrame.yPosition += 10;
            picFrame.Right();
            break;
        case Keys.Up:
            mouthcurrentposition = 2;
            picFrame.yPosition -= 10;
            picFrame.Up();
            break;
        case Keys.Down:
            mouthcurrentposition = 3;
            picFrame.yPosition += 10;
            picFrame.Down();
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have all the correct coding in place, I tried it on a simple picturebox in another project and it moved fine. I do not know what is stopping my picture box from moving in this case.

Answer (score 0):

```
pictureBox1.Location = new Point(x, y);
```

you can write some codes like this in your form key press event or keydown or keyup events. get the current picture box location and add up or Reduce the position.
you can use this code to get the current position :

```
pictureBox1.Location.X; //to get X
pictureBox1.Location.Y; // To get Y
```

Answer (score 0):

I know i'm super hella late but what you missed was `this.KeyDown += Pacman_KeyDown` on your main form

Comment: They have that in the form's constructor.